# How to use OpenCV on Qt 6 on MacOS Monterey

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opencv

I am trying to create an application on Qt 6.4 for facial recognition. For this, I want to use OpenCV4. I am using a widget-based application with qmake on QtCreator.
How am I supposed to use OpenCV in this application? I have installed OpenCV using brew on the terminal. What exactly am I supposed to do now?
I have a Mac M2 chip running MacOS 12.5. All the tutorials on the internet are on the outdated versions of Qt and OpenCV which are not working on the current version.

Comment: Both `Qt` and `OpenCV` are well documented with countless examples/tutorials.  Please be more specific about the problem(s) you're facing (preferably with some code).

Comment: I am not being able to include the OpenCV libraries. Whenever I try to, it gives a compilation "No matching file error". I have tried changing the path of the project to the location where the OpenCV library is installed using home-brew and even tried all other possible ways which are mentioned on the internet. However, I am not being able to find any tutorial specific to QT 6 and OpenCV 4 on the Apple Silicon Mac.